# Addition of STOP statement changes output value

Tags: linux, fortran, fedora

A value obtained for a (double precision) variable is written to the screen as part of my Fortran program. Following the `write` statement, the program continues uninterrupted.

However, when I add a `stop` statement immediately after the write, I get a different (screen printed) value for this variable. The change in values begins at the 6th significant digit.

The code includes:

```
enertot=energy0(x,y,z,size) !energy0 is a function
write (*,*) 'The initial energy is', enertot
```

This outputs some (plausible) value for `enertot` on the screen, and the program goes on.

Now adding the `stop`:

```
enertot=energy0(x,y,z,size) !energy0 is a function
write (*,*) 'The initial energy is', enertot
stop
```

This gives me a different value for `enertot`.

The same problem happens regardless of the compiler I use (f90/95 compilers). Could it have to do with the machine being very old, operating on an out of date Linux Fedora OS?

Even weirder - when I run the exact same program on my Windows laptop with the Silverfrost compiler, I get a third result for `enertot` altogether, differing from the previous results starting from the 5th significant digit. In this case, however, addition of the `stop` doesn't change the printed value at all.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you please reformat the source code?

Comment: What's the exact Fortran version? (And how old of Fedora?)

Comment: Adding a write statement can disable some compiler optimizations, so you can observe different results. Remember that you are doing floating point arithmetics and never believe that *all* the digits are exact.

Comment: Make a minimal code that can reproduce the problem.